# Wordpress. Как удалить из БД все записи/страницы, которые содержат "текст" в названии, содержании, превью?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Сабж. Предполагаю, что можно сделать обычной SQL инъекцией, но если записей/страниц очень много, то скрипт может и отвалиться по таймауту на shared-хостинге. Может есть какое-то решение?

Comment: Если нет твёрдого желания завалить сайт, то никакими "обычной SQL инъекцией" нельзя работать с ВП (кроме нескольких отдельных случаев). В твоём случае надо писать скрипт с использованием АПИ ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad , а нет примеров такого использования? Так-то понятно, что
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%Добро пожаловать%'; - и все дела

Comment: Ничего ты не понял.. НИКАКИХ прямых запров в базу! Тебе нужно https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_delete_post + https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query + возможно ещё  пр.

Comment: Вот такой код как раз точно завалит хостинг со скоростью обратки мне кажется, если мы будем сначала что-то селектить через wp_query, а потом удалять.